# Mysql Time zone is correct but time is 5 minutes earlier.(Asia/Kolkatta) time zone

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am using NOW() and the 'datetime' data type. Getting correct date but incorrect time. Like 50 mins earlier time from the current time.How to save the accurate time of the time zone.

eg: `SELECT NOW()`
This query gives 2021-08-19 17:40:17. But the actual time in my zone was 2021-08-19 17:45:17

Does anyone have any idea why this five minutes difference occurs?

Comment: SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+5:30');

Comment: It gives the time 2021-08-19 23:03:02. But actual time in my time zone is 2021-08-19 17:39:02

Comment: Sounds like the clock on your mysql machine is 5 minutes slow, rather than it being a time zone issue as such.

Comment: Anything else I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: You may try to configure using this instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the MySQL machine. It is five minutes slow. Solved the issue by adding five minutes in the insert query. `now() + interval 5 minute`